# Disable FIRRTL pass that checks for combinational loops

Tags: chisel

Is there a way to disable the CheckCombLoops FIRRTL pass? (These loops are false.)
If possible, I want to do this in the tester driver. I saw the option for the FIRRTL intepreter, but I still get an exception during the FIRRTL run. I also want to be able to use VCS as a backend.

```
class LazyStackNWait2Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  behavior of "LazyStackNWait2"
  it should "work" in {
    chisel3.iotesters.Driver.execute( Array( "--fr-allow-cycles", "--backend-name", "firrtl"), () => new LazyStackN(10, () => new LazyStackWait2)) { c =>
      new LazyStackNTester( c)
    } should be ( true)
  }
}
```

Here is part of the log:

```
[info] [1.057] Done elaborating.
[info] - should work *** FAILED ***
[info]   firrtl.passes.PassExceptions: 
firrtl.passes.CheckCombLoops$CombLoopException:  @[:@5437.2]: [module LazyStackN] Combinational loop detected:
```

The build is from the latest github HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This is now supported via the `--no-check-comb-loops`. [Relevant PR](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/pull/604)

There currently is not a way but I've created an issue to add this feature and it *shouldn't* be that difficult to do. https://github.com/ucb-bar/firrtl/issues/600

Just out of curiosity, what kind of false combinational loops are you seeing? We find that they are pretty rare* and usually easy to work around, so if you have any examples you can share I would greatly appreciate it.

* For example, they usually happen with aggregate types that have a dependence between subelements if the aggregate gets cast to bits and back (through a chisel3.util.Mux1H for example). Just trying to see what other common use patterns can cause false loops.

Comment: The paths are showing up between modules communicating through decoupled IOs. The controllers in the modules are complex and show false dependencies from ready (module input) to valid (module output) that will disappear after logic synthesis. I'm working on a FIRRTL transform to fix this issue and learning a lot.

Comment: @SteveBurns This is now supported, please see the above edit. It will be in the next release.